# the AJAX ERROR VALIDATION not showing in login page but it showing in developer mode console network in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication

the problem is when I submit the form the login get success when I do with right creational .But when I login with wrong info the validation message doesn't display error .

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Set default CSRF header
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    // Intercept login form
    $('#login-form').submit(function(e){

        // Prevent normal form submission, we well do in JS instead
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get form data
        var data = {
                email: $('[name=email]').val(),
                password: $('[name=password]').val(),
                remember: $('[name=remember]').val(),
            };

        // Send the request
        $.post($('this').attr('action'), data, function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                // If login success, redirect
                window.location.replace(response.redirect);
            }
        });
    });
```

Login Controller from and method here login and registering working very well but the only problem is validation message is not showing .

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        if($request->ajax()){
            // If request from AJAX
            return [
                'success' => true,
                'redirect' => $this->redirectPath() ?: route('home'),
            ];
        } else {
            // Normal POST do redirect
            return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                    ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }
    }
```

html form where id am trying to  showing or displaying errors when login

```
<form id="login-form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: It seems you are doing an Ajax Request in your code but I can't see the Javascript associated.

Comment: sorry I posted extend blade, now I am providing  ajax code

Comment: Sure, let me know when done

Comment: I have done now ,and thanks for showing interest to resolving my issue.

Comment: please check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a validation error in Ajax Format since your request is an Ajax request.
You can handle the errors in the Javascript directly:

I haven't tested it but it should give you some directions.

```
        $.post($('this').attr('action'), data, function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                // If login success, redirect
                window.location.replace(response.redirect);
            } else {
                if (response.errors.email)
                    $('#email-error').text(response.errors.email[0]);

                if (response.errors.password)
                    $('#password-error').text(response.errors.password[0]);
            }
        });
```

And modify your blade template as follow:

```
<form id="login-form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required
                   autofocus>
            <span class="help-block" id="email-error"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
            <span class="help-block" id="password-error"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Login
            </button>

            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                Forgot Your Password?
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: okay bro thanks for help , actually  I am new for jquery and ajax,  tcan you please show me how to do that thanks in advance .

Comment: alright, if you believe this is the solution, don't forget to put it as answered 

Comment: this is not working bro even i follow your answer as you said but error is not displaying.but i appreciate your help & afford :)